# magento open source full page cache

Tags: magento, caching

I was speaking to a developer recently who said that no magento CE full page cache worked perfectly even with a default install.

my experience of this is the same.

if you use aoe_static's awesome module and phoenix's full page cache with varnish module you will get close.

with the aoe_static module caching is done on a per Action basis which seems sensible to me. hole punching is done with placeholders applied via layout xml and dynamic blocks requested via a ajax call which won't be cached. cookies are set with this call as well. he provides a default vcl which is works with varnish 2 (i never checked) and can be easily changed for varnish 3.

cache invalidation is handled quite well by the phoenix module. you can see the methods in the control folder in the module. this takes care of cache invalidation when products or categories are changed and invalidates both product pages and category pages. however the url's generated by the layered nav are likely to be cached (depending on your vcl). these are not invalidated, so watch out folks.

i'd really like to know if any other problems exist with these modules before i use them on production sites. if anyone could point me to a problem i'd be happy to try and post a solution.

but for the layered nav url's a model would be required to log the generated url's with category id. i suppose it would be simple to have a 2 column model - url and category - and then cache invalidation would need to check the model and invalidate the extra url.  this should be done at the same time as the main category url gets done. doesn't sound too bad. if anyone gets my very brief explanation please advise on if i'm missing something before i waste my time.

i would rather create an open source project with some community help (or someone more experienced at the lead) that has a (deserved) reputation for reliability in a default 1.7 install at least.  i think the most sensible thing would be to create one module with all the edge cases (for a default 1.7 install) covered or documented.

does anyone know how to go about such a mission? if there was more community support to do this with apc or memcached that might be more sensible for wider hosting availability. the logic or the development time wouldn't change much.

this could be expanded to cover session caching of blocks which should be kept in mind but i think focus on a reliable full page cache should be the priority.

you can also detect devices in a vcl. this could be added to shops wanting mobile version https://github.com/varnish/varnish-devicedetect/blob/master/devicedetect.vcl

i've created an email for this project so if you want to be involved it's "magefpc gmail com". anyone with experience of magento, git and debugging would be welcome.

thanks

Comment: Not really an answer, but we've used the Phoenix mouldule on a number of sites, and made a number of extensions around turning on/off caching based on certain events, and introduced a cookie based system for maintaining some user data client side.  We maintain a public GitHub repo for our version of the module at https://github.com/aligent/Phoenix_VarnishCache ...  We;ve also seen (but not used) Nexcess' Turpentine module (https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine).  Turpentine has a much simpler implementation, and looks interesting.  We'd be happy to assist in any way we can.

Comment: excellent your offer is much appreciated! i looked at your code and it seems pretty sound but takes a very different approach. i believe we should wait a couple of weeks to see more variations and weigh up the pros and cons. anyways invalidation is needed for the layered nav url's but should tie into a complete module i believe

Comment: i've thought a little more and am coming to the conclusion that i really like using the phoenix module and aoe_static's module. like i said your approach to dynamic content is very different. however your integration with the AW Blog is a brilliant idea and essential to most business's. i really think refactoring these elements and adding the cache invalidation i described into one module is a good approach. i'd like to check that the creators of the other modules would be happy with this and give something a go. what you think? we seem to be alone on this issue for now :(

Comment: The Phoenix module is OSL licensed, so there shouldn't be an issue there, I assume aoe_static is the same.  I haven't looked at aoe_static, but we use aoe_scheduler on most sites we do, and it's excellent.

Comment: yes he's a cool guy and there's not even a license on the aoe_static module. this idea seems pretty sound to me but would require a bit of work and plenty of testing. i think a coherent single module structured this way would be quite easy to adapt to most shops. is more work needed than has been basically described thus far?

Comment: spent some time diving into repeated functionality in the madalinoprea module but doesn't seem to add anything that's needed unless i'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

1 problem what you might have with aoe_static is, that currently the extension doesnt log products so statistics in backend about viewed products are not updated. this was added recently as TODO note into the github.

problem with varnish and magento cache is, that magento cache parts of pages, blocks and varnish does cache whole pages. so even though phoenix solution have observers in place and reset varnish accordingly on product/category update, you still have blocks in magento what have to be reseted. aoe_static try's to solve this, but it does only for visible blocks on the page. but other parts of magento, as layered navigation, might be reseted as well internally on product/category update, but than are not reset in varnish.
there are 2 solutions. either identify every part of magento on frontend whats not reset after product/category update and apply aoe_static solution to it. that would mean you would have to load layered nav via ajax.
or the second solution is, to add more logic into phoenix extension to invalidate more varnish pages.

i have couple of custom extensions (pages what display products) and i build logic to invalidate those extensions each time product/category is updated. now im working on search, as this needs to be invalidated as well, but the complicated part is, to work around blocks and cache invalidation logic.

overall, proper cache invalidation is one of the hardest part of web development.

Comment: your post seems important and accurate. the end result of this is going to be repeated trips to the server. this is an expensive but easily managed problem with load balanced setups. we'll achieve the desired result of reliable cached responses if we manage the ideas of the aoe_static and other modules in a more comprehensive manner (i hope). like you say it's a difficult area but one the community will run into again and again. much better i think to handle this in  a community way with the experiences of many being added and branched on git. i didn't wanted to cache search yet.

Comment: I'm reminded of a quote from Phil Karlton:
"There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things."

Comment: big style :) but so many people use it and the logic of ajax requests and load balanced servers greatly reduces our difficulties. so long as a a comprehensive approach is taken a very reliable module can exist. i'm actually quite new to programming. at first i was amazed at what could be done, now i'm shocked at what gets pushed to a production environment and absolutely refuse to release half finished work. look at the FPC problems detailed on SO, many are problems encountered by end users!!

Comment: the only problem i have with aoe_static is, that on every ajax request  it initialize the whole magento app just to generate block. while doing this, magento does a lot of unnecessary (at that time) database and file requests. so at the end it produce almost the same load on server as uncached request. the benefit is, that user gets main part of the page much faster, via varnish, and dynamic part later. also you should get beter marks from google with this approach.

Comment: i said in the first comment "repeated trips to the server" oops. anyways i don't see any need now. dynamic content can be handled in one request which stress you database. just need place holders and product info sent to server for processing in one call. this is a little awkward but not too bad. use an observer, set a cookie with product info, append cookie in vclhash  and set in vcl_deliver. it's 5 in the morning here. that might not work

Answer (score 1):

i'd like this post to be a community answer detailing approaches to particular handles and suggested caching and invalidation logic needed if it's not already included in the phoenix or aoe_static module. basically caching will be done by module/controller/action pattern laid out in the aoe_static module and most of the existing invalidation exists in the Phoenix module.

so we need to decide which blocks should be rendered via ajax and where addition cache invalidation is required. like gondo says you'll need to add a lot more invalidation logic to cache searches. i plan to start smaller with the catalog, cms and aw blog pages, much has been done here but a little more is required. if we could add search too, with the help from gondo :), that would be great.

for instance - widget instances could be a problem, as could static block saves. this can (as far as my very quick investigation has shown) be easily solved only by running a total cache invalidation using the event dispatched by the core_model_abstract method _beforeSave()

```
  Mage::dispatchEvent('model_save_before', array('object'=>$this));
```

we'd need to match the type of model before invalidating the entire cache. this pattern will also be a real time saver in other difficult areas of cache invalidation. using the instanceof method is fine but we'll need to know model names to check for. i guess community involvement is great here because the code's so easy but so is missing a model.

widgets are essentially the same from frontend point of view. the one with products should be loaded with aoe_static, as they are changing quite often. but the static ones can be treated as static (html) blocks.

we don't want to invalidate the entire cache when a product is saved and can't check if the product has been included in a widget. but the aoe_static module works with layout rendering. widgets will need to be included via layout xml and not in the admin wysiwyg as the often are. these widgets could be added to the call controller handle and place holders to what ever handle is needed.

full varnish invalidation, time to time, is not a bed thing. the whole cache invalidation is an issue if it happens too often, or if it does not happen when needed. the main goal should be to capture every invalidation scenario and trigger notice in admin panel, same type of message as you get when you save product: "One or more of the Cache Types are invalidated..."
this way admin can make the decision if he/she wants to invalidate cache manually or wait. and ofc there can be some automatic invalidation logic build in based on this scenarios.

also the model must be created to store the url's created by layered nav and these should be invalidated along with the category view url's.

and with layered nav and invalidation in general in mind we must invalidate the entire cache when an attribute is saved (i think).

we should be able to put the product reviews on the product page without ajax for seo purposes.

this means when a review model is saved it must be checked using the model_save_before event and we should invalidate the product page url.
this save changes the rating but i suggest this block is grabbed in the ajax call. it's not important for seo. this goes for the product view and list pages.

we could also cache and invalidate review module pages but this isn't important to the majority of users and should wait.

who wants tags blocks. these can't be loaded by ajax it defeats their purpose. at the same time they're not worth our efforts now imo.

if you cache url's with the session id appended it will cause users to get each others sessions i'm told. i think this is easily solved by piping in vcl_fetch based on a regex.

this answer is getting messy and should be redrafted sometime soon. feel free to add your 2 cents!!